# Generate chart/graph for WHO baby percentile/z-scores

Tags: python, graph, charts

I don't have a lot of programming (web or otherwise) experience. So coming from that perspective, I'm trying to tackle a little self-imposed project, wherein I am going to attempt, a very basic, minimal, but attractive (think bootstrap or helium) website, where you can enter your baby's sex, age, weight, length, head circumference etc, and will then be presented with an attractive percentile/z score graph/chart for you baby's z-scores (I know there are sites that do this, but they are dreadful, ugly, and usually don't give you any sort of nice-looking chart/graph etc).

So I'm thinking of using this as a project to learn python as there exists this python z-score calculator based on WHO data:
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pygrowup/0.7b0

So the form data would pass to the appropriate variables in this python script (I would think), and then, I would need a chart/graph python library to generate the chart I would think?

Perhaps Python graphtool?
http://projects.skewed.de/graph-tool/

Or maybe just use highcharts (javascript)

Any ideas on this would be very helpful.. not asking for someone to do it for me obviously, just maybe some pointers on how to get started etc, and possibly some suggestions on how to generate the chart/graph etc.

Comment: Did you try cartesius (http://tkrajina.github.com/cartesius/) ? (Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of the library, but I thinks it is on-topic here).

Answer (score 0):

You could do all of that on the client side with javascript / JQuery. For charts, I would also look intp d3, it makes beautiful charts in Javascript. Doing it on the client side would be much easier than dealing with posts to a python layer. You could however use something lightweight like Flask if you want to learn web dev with python. Flask would provide the frame work and templating with Jinja2, and all of the calculation would be done client side. THat would be my 2 cents. . .

http://flask.pocoo.org/

http://d3js.org/